# record the values in ascending in dataframe

Tags: python, sorting, dataframe

is a table of the following form

```
numbers  
0   2,4,9,1,3  
1   10,5,8,2  
2   4,8  
3   5,2,9,6
4   3,8,5,1
```

how to record the values ​​in ascending?
need to get a table of the following form

```
 numbers  
0   1,2,3,4,9  
1   2,5,8,10
2   4,8  
3   2,5,6,9
4   1,3,5,8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the strings, sort the integers and then join them back as strings:

```
df.numbers.apply(lambda x: ','.join(map(str, sorted(map(int, x.split(","))))))

#0    1,2,3,4,9
#1     2,5,8,10
#2          4,8
#3      2,5,6,9
#4      1,3,5,8
#Name: numbers, dtype: object
```

You can assign this back to column `numbers` if you want to change the column to the new sorted version:

```
df['numbers'] = df.numbers.apply(lambda x: ','.join(map(str, sorted(map(int, x.split(","))))))
```

Comment: then how to write again in dataframe? @Psidom

Comment: You can assign it to the data frame column.

Comment: Thank you very much @Psidom